# Emotion Styled Components not autocompleting in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm, emotion

I'm using `@emotion/styled` in WebStorm and there's no Intellisense (or whatever it's called in WebStorm) for autocomplete within my style object. Typescript does appear to be checking to some degree:

```js
const StepTimer = styled.button({
  borderRadius: 50,
  height: '30px',
  blorg: 3, // does not give a TS error for unknown key
  display: 1 // gives a TS error for incorrect value type
})
```

VSCode on the same computer gives autocomplete inside the object, although not for values (e.g., I don't get options for `display`'s value like `block, inline,` etc.)

Is there some setting I have wrong? I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately even 1 year later object syntax is not supported by WebStorm (even when in language settings it says that JSX is supported but object syntax has nothing to do with JSX). I can actually get some IntelliSense for property names, but no values, so that matches your experience in VSCode.

However you can use template string syntax and it gives you auto-completion for CSS as expected:

```js
const StepTimer = styled.button`
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  blorg: 3;
  display: 1;
`
```

Something to note: for `blorg` you'll get Unknown property warning and for `display: 1` you'll get a Mismatched property value error in WS.

With this syntax you get color highlights and that will even work when you need to customize styles based on properties

```js
const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${({variant}) => variant === 'secondary' ? `white` : `#434449`};
  background-color: ${({variant}) => variant === 'secondary' ? `#3f51b5` : `#f1f2f7`};
`
```

[image: syntax hints]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use WebStorm's Styled Components plug-in

Comment: Could you add some explanation to why this is the solution? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project is using ReactJSX as its JS version.

Open Webstorm Preferences and go to `Languages & Frameworks > Javascript`  There must be a Javascript Language version configuration. Select `React JSX` from the dropdown.

Just as a reminder, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for access Preferences dialog.